# Can I use Chrome Enterprise deployment to secure extensions on my child's Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, parental-controls, screen-time, mdm

I want to 'force install' some extensions on my son's Mac (to limit access to sites), and was looking at [Chrome Deployment documentation.](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9020078?hl=en&ref_topic=7650028)

I'm at a loss on the last step ... is there a way to install Chrome on his Mac with policies in effect, without paying for an expensive professional MDM?

Unfortunately Apple's Screen Time does not work in Chrome (yet).

Answer (score 0):

for the answer please see below. Just a question: How old is you son? Have you talked to him already about your limits and expectations? If you were my dad, I would really appreciate when we sit down together and make an agreement about proper device usage before using parental controls. If this doesn't work, you can can still offer your child to help him by using parental controls.  All the best!

You can manage the browser via admin.google.com. There you can register a free account. This will allow you to generate a file with a unique ID, which you have to put in a certain directory on your Mac. There is also a further opportunity to set local rules for the browser. For example you can enter in the terminal on your Mac "write com.google.Chrome SafeSitesFilterBehavior -integer 1" This will block mature content. BTW My Chrome browser is managed. Actually, I'm the admin and force myself to block mature content.